# Right align text in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

```
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3.35cm}||p{5cm}|l|}
\hline
\thead{Område} & \thead{Positive konsekvenser} & \thead{Negative konsekvenser} \\
\hline \hline
\textbf{Arbejdsfordeling} & Et nyt slags produkt giver næsten altid ny arbejdskraft & \\
\hline
\textbf{Infrastruktur} &  & \\
\hline
\textbf{De fysiske ressourcer} &  & \\
\hline
\textbf{Den offentlige sektor} &  & \\
\hline
\textbf{NGO'er} &  & \\
\hline
\textbf{Befolkningens levevilkår} &  & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
```

And it produces this output:

[image: Table]

How do I get the text in the left column aligned like the middle column row 2? I use the     {p{xcm}}     command but i don't know how to align it as with "c", "l" and "r".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that something like that you want? I suppose you loaded  the `makecell` package in your preamble. I added using `hhline` for better-looking `\hlines` and `vlines` (although only horizontal lines, as suggested by the `booktabs` package look still better). I also loaded `ragged2e` to have reasonable hyphenation  in column,  and  `cellspace` for a less tight vertical spacing in tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell, ragged2e}%
\renewcommand*\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage{hhline}
\newcommand\myhline{\hhline{|-||-|-|}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| >{\RaggedRight\bfseries}S{p{3.35cm}}||p{5cm}|l|}
\myhline
\thead{Område} & \thead{Positive konsekvenser} & \thead{Negative konsekvenser} \\
\hhline{:=::=:=:}
Arbejdsfordeling & Et nyt slags produkt giver næsten altid ny arbejdskraft & \\
\myhline
Infrastruktur &  & \\
\myhline
De fysiske ressourcer &  & \\
\myhline
Den offentlige sektor &  & \\
\myhline
NGO'er &  & \\
\myhline
Befolkningens levevilkår &  & \\
\myhline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No need of complicated settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\usepackage{array,ragged2e,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  >{\RaggedRight\bfseries}p{3cm}
  >{\RaggedRight}p{4cm}
  l
  @{}
 }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Område} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Positive konsekvenser} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Negative konsekvenser} \\
\midrule
Arbejdsfordeling & Et nyt slags produkt giver næsten altid ny arbejdskraft & \\
\addlinespace
Infrastruktur &  & \\
\addlinespace
De fysiske ressourcer &  & \\
\addlinespace
Den offentlige sektor &  & \\
\addlinespace
NGO'er &  & \\
\addlinespace
Befolkningens levevilkår &  & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want a ruled table (which you don't, trust me), use the features by `hhline`. But never ever use double rules.